# dangerous behavior of lapack routin zheev

Tags: matrix, fortran, lapack, eigenvalue

I stumbled upon an odd behavior when using the lapack routine `zheev()`. There are two issues which I do not understand

1) One of my global variables seems to be overwritten by `zheev()`. The following small program shows it:

[compiled with `gfortran -o test test.f90 -llapack -lblas`]

```
program test    
implicit none

integer, parameter :: dp = 8
integer, parameter :: dim = 3

integer :: l

real(dp), parameter :: kmin = -0.03_dp
real(dp), parameter :: kmax = 0.03_dp
integer, parameter  :: steps = 100
real(dp) :: stepD = (kmax - kmin)/real(steps)
complex(dp) :: matrix(dim,dim)=0.

integer :: info
integer :: rwork=3*dim-2, lwork, lwmax=100
real(dp) :: evals(dim) 
complex(dp) :: work(3*dim-2)

lwork=-1
call zheev('N','U',size(matrix,1), matrix, dim, evals, work, lwork, &
            rwork, info) 
lwork = min( lwmax, int( work(1) ))

do l = 0, 3
    write(*,*) stepD
    call zheev('N', 'U', size(matrix,1), matrix, dim, evals, work, &
    lwork, rwork, info) 
    write(*,*) stepD
end do

end program test
```

The output is

```
5.9999999999999995E-004
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000
```

This can be cured by setting stepD to a parameter. But I do not understand this behavior. It is getting even more weird:

2) Setting `lwork` in the definition to some value like

```
integer :: rwork=3*dim-2, lwork=10, lwmax=100
```

(simply change the corresponding line above)
gives the following result:

```
   5.9999999999999995E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
   5.9999991208314896E-004
```

How can this happen? Setting `lwork` to 10 should have no effect since later on it is set to -1. An important notion is: If one removes

```
lwork=-1
call zheev('N','U',size(matrix,1), matrix, dim, evals, work, lwork, &
            rwork, info) 
lwork = min( lwmax, int( work(1) ))
```

the code works fine.

Comment: Any relation to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322226/inaccurate-zheev-eigen-values-and-vectors. See also the discussion about `kind` with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302912/incorrect-inconsistent-results-from-zgeev-lapack

Comment: I've related this to an answer with a different subroutine: it still comes down to having the correct arguments.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler did not complain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of zheev (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d9a/group__complex16_h_eeigen_gaf23fb5b3ae38072ef4890ba43d5cfea2.html#gaf23fb5b3ae38072ef4890ba43d5cfea2):

```
subroutine zheev    (   character   JOBZ,
        character   UPLO,
        integer     N,
        complex*16, dimension( lda, * )     A,
        integer     LDA,
        double precision, dimension( * )    W,
        complex*16, dimension( * )      WORK,
        integer     LWORK,
        double precision, dimension( * )    RWORK,
        integer     INFO 
    )
```

here we see that `RWORK` is an array of type double precision, but in the supplied code `rwork` is a scalar integer

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler complain?

Comment: No the compiler has no knowledge of the interface unless you explicitly use and `interface` in your program or it is handled by means of a module (but they are, as far as I know, not provided by LaPack and are also compiler dependent. It is possible to generate interfaces yourself, but for the gfortran compiler I don't know the options,  for the Intel compiler see the options `-gen_interfaces -warn interfaces -module`).